# Fully populated ko.observableArray will not show in Template using foreach

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, foreach

I am trying to separate a list of JSON data into segments ("sliders") and have succeeded in creating a data object in the format I want, however the foreach binding is not working as expected.

HTML Template:

```
    <div class="slide" data-bind="foreach: actionSliders">
                Stuff
    </div>
```

Here is my relevant Knockout code:

```
function Slider() {
    this.actions = ko.observableArray([]);      
}

var viewModel = {
    actionSliders: ko.observableArray([])
};

viewModel.loadData = function() {       
//LOAD Actions from API
       jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+'/api/actions/get_author_posts/',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (ActionData) {

            console.log('getJSON data - Actions',ActionData.posts);

            var actionSlidersCount = 0; 
            viewModel.actionSliders([]);

            //create the first slider array
            viewModel.actionSliders().push(new Slider());
            viewModel.actionSliders()[0].actions([]);

            jQuery.each(ActionData.posts, function(index) {

                    // add each action to the current slider
                    viewModel.actionSliders()[actionSlidersCount].actions().push(new Action(this));

                    //add a new slider every 5 records
                    var calc = (parseInt(index)+1)%5;
                    if(calc ==0 ){
                        //new slider
                        actionSlidersCount++;
                        viewModel.actionSliders().push(new Slider());
                        viewModel.actionSliders()[actionSlidersCount].actions([]);
                    }                               
             });                
             console.log('ActionSliders',viewModel.actionSliders());
            },
            data: { },
            async: true
        }); 

};
```

This is what my data looks like in the console:

```
ActionSliders 
[Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider, sortNum: function, random: function, sum: function, max: function, min: function…]
    0: Slider
        actions: Object[0]
        __proto__: Slider
    1: Slider
    2: Slider
    3: Slider
    4: Slider
    5: Slider
    6: Slider
    length: 7
    __proto__: Array[0]

* I can access all the data with console commands:

> viewModel.actionSliders()[0].actions()[0]

Action {id: 197, title: "Turned off the tap while brushing my teeth"…}

> viewModel.actionSliders()

[ Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider, Slider]
```

So, as you can see, in the working model (no errors in console, no data-bind errors), the object is fully populated with data, and in the template, "stuff" should repeat 6 times - once for each Slider, but the loop isn't even working.  Is there a problem with having observable arrays inside of others?  Am I missing something in the way I am creating the Slider objects?  Any advice is most welcome, please.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that may be easier to read:

http://jsfiddle.net/earthman/wTzFp/10/

Comment: JSFiddle should provide an actual working example of a problem.  It's not simply for formatting.  Could you please update your jsFiddle to highlight the problem you're having.  Get rid of the ajax call and just hard-code the JSON data and point out where your data binding is failing.  Often times, going through the exercise of create a jsFiddle that highlights the problem leads to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it was a two part issue.

The reason why foreach wasn't working was because I was pushing to the function, instead of the array. I needed to use:

```
viewModel.actionSliders.push(new Slider());
```

instead of:

```
viewModel.actionSliders().push(new Slider());
```

Once I did that, the foreach worked for the main object

Then, I realized I needed to inject the data *inside* the class, instead of from outside.  To remedy that, I modified the code like this:

```
        var tempActionArray = [];

        jQuery.each(ActionData.posts, function(index) {
            //add an action to the current slider
            var tempAction = new Action(this);
            tempActionArray.push(tempAction);

            var calc = (parseInt(index)+1)%5;
            if(calc ==0 ){
                //add a new slider
                actionSlidersCount++;
                viewModel.actionSliders.push(new Slider(tempActionArray));

                //reset temp array
                tempActionArray = [];
                        //viewModel.actionSliders[actionSlidersCount].actions([]);  
            }

        });

        function Slider(data) {
        var data = data || [];
        this.actions = ko.observableArray([]);
        var Actions = [];
        //console.log("slider data",data)
        jQuery.each(data, function(index) {
            //console.log("action index",data[index])
            Actions.push(data[index]);
        }); 
        this.actions = Actions; 
    }
```

and now all is good in the world!  :)  Moving on...

Answer (score 0):

Since you pushed `new Slider` object into your `actionSliders` observableArray I guessing the structure might be like this:

```
actionSliders = [
 {
   actions = {}
 },
 {
   actions = {}
  }
];
```

I'm sorry if this doesn't work for your, but how if you try to bind it like this ? :

```
<div class="slide" data-bind="foreach: actionSliders().actions">
    Stuff
</div>
```

Comment: The way I want to bind it is using a nested template - I want to do a foreach for actionsliders, then have a nested foreach for the actions.  The problem right now is that foreach is not working, but the data is there.